# Why am I getting a 404 when I run my Azure Function locally?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've setup a very simple Azure Function in C# to respond to an `HttpTrigger`. When I run the function locally following [Microsoft Azure instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings), all I'm getting back is an empty 404 response.

I'm using [Visual Studio 2017 v15.3 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) with the [Azure Function Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewBHall-MSFT.AzureFunctionToolsforVisualStudio2017) extension installed. This is the code for my Azure Function:

```
[FunctionName("Func1")]        
public static async Task<object> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, WebHookType = "genericJson")]
    HttpRequestMessage req, 
    TraceWriter log)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

When I run it locally (by right-clicking the VS project and going Debug > Start new instance) it seems to launch just fine. My function is recognized and the URL given for it is http://localhost:7071/api/Func1

However, When I GET or POST to the above URL (with a Content-Type header set to "application/json") I get back an empty 404 response. The Azure Functions CLI console outputs:

> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM] Executing HTTP request: {
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "requestId": "ae247ea6-c055-40f5-a09c-40ea207cc785",
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "method": "GET",
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "uri": "/api/Func1"
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM] }
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM] Executed HTTP request: {
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "requestId": "ae247ea6-c055-40f5-a09c-40ea207cc785",
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "method": "GET",
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "uri": "/api/Func1",
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "authorizationLevel": "Anonymous"
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM] }
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM] Response details: {
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "requestId": "ae247ea6-c055-40f5-a09c-40ea207cc785",
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM]   "status": "NotFound"
>
> [6/12/2017 12:26:12 PM] }

Why am I getting a 404 and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify the `methods` parameter, e.g.

```cs
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET")]
```

Comment: For me, it only works with `GET`, no matter what I set there as accepted methods. Any ideas?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati If you go into your Azure Functions and click the "Integrate" tab you should see a "Selected HTTP Methods" area with a bunch of little check boxes. GET is set by default but you have to enable to rest. Took me some time to find this so I hope this helps!

Comment: @JeffL How does this work if you are building the function locally though... Having the same issue with only GET working